# org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate does not add new columns to existing table definitions

Tags: mysql, hibernate, migration, hibernate-5.x, hibernate-4.x

We recently upgraded from Hibernate 4.3 to Hibernate 5.4.

Previously we used to use invoke the SchemaUpdate in the following manner

```
 new SchemaUpdate(sessionFactory.getConfiguration()).execute(false, true);
```

This would create new tables and update existing tables with any new columns that were created.

After we upgraded to Hibernate 5.4, we have changed it to the following

```
schemaUpdate.execute(EnumSet.of(TargetType.DATABASE), metadata, serviceRegistry);
```

This still creates the new tables,but does not add any new columns added to existing table definitions.

In the previous version, the execute method had a doUpdate argument which am not sure how to pass in to schemaUpdate anymore in 5.4

Thank you for your time and support